# Is there a way to clone the deployed data service on the WSO2 DSS

Tags: web-services, clone, wso2, dataservice

I created a data web service on the WSO2 Data Services server, now I would like to use it as a template so I can create more services out of it.
Is there a way to copy/paste the service XML to a new one?
I would like to skip the wizard mode creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to service Dashboard and there you have "edit data service (xml edit)" option available. That can be reused to create similar services. create a .dbs file out of that xml content and deploy through upload data service option in the management console (Change the data service's name). Following link would be useful.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/Work-In-Progress+Service

Comment: thanks!that worked for me. I didn't know that the .dbs files holds only the xml exposed by the editor.